# if else WP is_user_logged_in doesn't show correct content

Tags: php, wordpress

I just write following code

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{
    $filter = array(
        'post_status' => 'private',
    );
} 
else 
{
    $filter = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
}
```

I have header with token so should it work.
But always appears 'publish' posts

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you've got a few issues. First and foremost, make sure your code is properly formatted with indents/spaces. It gets **very** hard to read very quickly without having a consistent formatting structure:

[image: Screenshot of properly indented and formatted code]

With that said, it seems like you've got a ways to go on understanding the fundamentals of WordPress programming, and/or you're not including all of the code. For instance, what does `$filter` reference, when/where is this code being run? You're either missing the surrounding code in your example, or you just put this code somewhere and there's nothing for it to reference and modify.

WordPress makes use of a [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and is extensible via [Filter Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and [Action Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). You'll need at least a general understanding of those, as well as ["The Loop"](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/), in order to really get WordPress to do what you want.

Based on the snippet you've provided, it looks like you want to display only private posts to users that are logged in, I'm assuming in your main query. You can make use of the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) hook to modify a WP Loop query. Something like this should get you started:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query_if_logged_in' );
function modify_query_if_logged_in( $query ){
    // Abort if we're in /wp-admin or this isn't the main query
    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        // If user is logged in
        if( is_user_logged_in() ){
            // Only show private posts
            $query->set( 'post_status', 'private' );
        }
    }
}
```

Just drop that in your `functions.php` file and it should work. You can also add in any other conditions you want, like [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) to only have it run on the home page (which sort of makes `! is_admin()` redundant and unnecessary), or adjust the `$query` to show both regular *and* private posts with `$query->set( 'post_status', array('private', 'publish') );`